# bond with different VLAN's, all uses same MAC-Addresses / is it possible to generate the MAC automatically?

Tags: netplan, network-bonding, vlan

the config is done as follows with the configurator in the setup wizard:

```
network:
  bonds:
    team0:
      interfaces:
      - enp65s0f0np0
      - enp65s0f1np1
      parameters:
        lacp-rate: slow
        mode: 802.3ad
        transmit-hash-policy: layer2
  ethernets:
    enp65s0f0np0: {}
    enp65s0f1np1: {}
  version: 2
  vlans:
    team0.10:
      addresses:
      - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx
      id: 10
      link: team0
      mtu: 1500
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx
        - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx
        search:
        - sub.domain.com
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx
    team0.100:
      addresses:
      - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx
      id: 100
      link: team0
      mtu: 9000
      nameservers:
        addresses: []
        search: []
    team0.101:
      addresses:
      - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx
      id: 101
      link: team0
      mtu: 9000
      nameservers:
        addresses: []
        search: []
```

But the mac-addresses of all interfaces are the same (ip a):

[image: Picture -> ip a]

Has somebody a solution for the problem?

Thanks in advance